# Is setting columns of a dataframe through iloc slicing safe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Lets say I have some simple dataframe with 10 columns and n rows. Many of the rows have some NaN values, so I use scikit-learn's imputer to fill those values.

However, the first three columns are essentially indices so I don't need to fill NaN's there.

Therefore, I have an implementation like this:

```
imp = sklearn.impute.KNNImputer()

t = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, 3:]), columns=df.columns[3:])
df.iloc[:, 3:] = t
```

By looking at df.head() and df.shape, nothing seems to have gone horrifically wrong. However I've learned not to trust pandas completely when it comes to slicing dataframes.

Is there any obvious flaw to this approach?

Comment: you can subset your columns, but why would you not trust pandas for this? it sounds more like you have a problem with your data model?

Comment: @Datanovice because it's not always clear whether it's a slice/view/copy I guess#

Comment: FWIW I don't see an issue with what you did. You can always restart the python interpreter and see whether you get the notorious "setting values with a ...." warning (since you'll only get that once)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of being reliant on `.iloc` you can return a dataframe containing the columns you need to access by passing in a list of columns.

Given a 2d pandas dataframe

`df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', ...]]` will return the same as `df.iloc[:, 3:]`

Additionally, you can assign new values to the columns like this:

```
df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', ...]] = SOME TRANSFORMATION OF THE ORIGINAL OBJECT
```

So in your case, we'd simply write:

```
cols_to_impute = df.columns[3:]
df[cols_to_impute] = imp.fit_transform(df[cols_to_impute])
```

Additionally, it's important to note that the list `cols_to_impute` could be in any order and you would still get the same results. So you can use this method for cases where the imputed columns are not in the first three columns and not have to worry about indexing.